# How can I set ordinal based DNS names for ASG instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, user-data

## Problem

In my dev environment I want to create easy to remember ordinal dns names for ECS cluster hosts.  When we deploy we scale out from 1 to 2 hosts and then drain/scale back in.

At present we use userdata like so so set the dns name

```
INSTANCE_ID=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
INSTANCE_IP=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4)
RECORD_CONFIG="/tmp/ecs-a-record.json"

cat >>$RECORD_CONFIG << ROUTE53
{
  "Comment": "Create a friendly DNS name for the DOD ECS host",
  "Changes": [{
  "Action": "UPSERT",
    "ResourceRecordSet": {
      "Name": "dev-ecs.ourenv.dev",
      "Type": "A",
      "TTL": 300,
      "ResourceRecords": [{ "Value": "$INSTANCE_IP"}]
    }
  }]
}
ROUTE53

aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id ... --change-batch file://$RECORD_CONFIG
```

I think my options are

- probe dns name and if its in use, increment a counter, try again with N+1
- use aws cli to gather data about the ASG instances and use launch time to determine ordinal name

Does anyone know of a more elegant solution?

Comment: This is the "pets vs cattle" syndrome. Have a think about _why_ you want an ordinal number against each instance. The instances in the Auto Scaling group can be identified by a tag, and they each have an InstanceId that uniquely identifies them, so the only 'benefit' of an ordinal number is for us poor humans who can't remember long (but unique) numbers. Plus, as instances are terminated and launched, the numbers will become disjointed or re-used (eg when instance 5 of 5 is terminated, should the next instance be 5, or should it be 6?). So, do consider whether it is actually worth doing.

Comment: That's a fair point.  This is more about ease of debugging in dev envs. We normally run a single node ecs cluster to make sshing to the instance to experimentation easy.  When we deploy, we scale out to two and scale back in upon completion.  However, that can result in messing up the DNS due to our original userdata.  I just updated it to use ordinals so that's now less of risk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here's how we manage convenience fqdns records for devTest environments.  This becomes important when we scale the cluster to ensure the 2nd/3rd hosts don't attempt to take the 1st host's name

```
checkHostExists() {
  host=$1
  nc -z $host 22 >> /dev/null 2>&1 ; echo $?
}

findDevTestDNSName() {
  base_name=$1
  domain=$2
  count=1
  name=$(printf "%s%02d.%s" $base_name $count $domain)

  while [[ "$(checkHostExists $name)" -eq "0"  ]]
  do
    count=$((count+1))
    name=$(printf "%s%02d.%s" $base_name $count $domain)
  done
  echo $name
}


##
# Main Userdata context
#
# Please Note: This is a Terraform template
#  ${foo} refers to a foo variable passed to the template
#  $${bar} refers to an actual env variable
# when terraform resolves the template then tf vars are replaced with
# concrete values in the usedata
##

# lookup the instance ID
INSTANCE_ID=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
INSTANCE_IP=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4)

if [[ "${cluster_name}" =~ "devtest" ]]; then
  # create a friendly hostname for the ECS host if this is a development test env

  # install nmap/nc for host probing
  yum install -y nmap

  ECS_HOST_FQDNS=$(findDevTestDNSName ${cluster_name}-ecs ${dns_domain})
  HOST_NAME=$(echo $ECS_HOST_FQDNS|sed 's/\..*//')
  echo Setting DevTest ECS Hostname: $${ECS_HOST_FQDNS}

    RECORD_CONFIG="/tmp/ecs-a-record.json"
    cat >>$RECORD_CONFIG << ROUTE53
    {
      "Comment": "Create a friendly DNS name for the ${cluster_name} ECS host",
      "Changes": [{
      "Action": "UPSERT",
        "ResourceRecordSet": {
          "Name": "$${ECS_HOST_FQDNS}",
          "Type": "A",
          "TTL": 300,
          "ResourceRecords": [{ "Value": "$INSTANCE_IP"}]
        }
      }]
    }
    ROUTE53

    aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id ${dns_zone_id} --change-batch file://$RECORD_CONFIG

fi
```