# How can I increment a hostname in EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53

I want to be able to launch an AMI of count 100 instances and would like the hostnames to be increments of serv01, serv02, etc. I need to increment that hostname for each host so each host has a unique name.

What is the best method to achieve increments hostname, through UserData, CloudFormation, or Route53?

What is the script that I need to put in the UserData to achieve the increments hostname? I need to launch 100 Linux EC2 instances and would like each instance to have a increment hostname and private IP address of the EC2 instance added to the /etc/hosts file.

Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Similar to: [How can I set ordinal based DNS names for ASG instances](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64394258/174777)

Answer (score 2):

If you are launching all the instances in the same `RunInstances()` by specifying a `count`, then an `ami-launch-index` value is provided:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/ami-launch-index
```

See: [Example: AMI launch index value - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMI-launch-index-examples.html)

This value can be used to associate a unique value with each instance, such as setting a Tag name. (This would need to be done *from the instance itself* since that is the only way to retrieve the value.)

Comment: How would I add the "count" in the UserData script? Would it be easier to get this done through Route53?

Comment: You can write a script that retrieves the `ami-launch-index` via the above URL. You can then use it to tag the instance ([create-tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-tags.html)) or update a Route 53 record ([Amazon Route 53: How to automatically update IP addresses without using Elastic IPs - DEV Community](https://dev.to/aws/amazon-route-53-how-to-automatically-update-ip-addresses-without-using-elastic-ips-h7o)).

Comment: Is there a way to increment the tags creation? For example I would like to launch 30 EC2 spot instances with increment tags, and automatically register these tags with local-IP4 on Route53.

Comment: Tags are associated with instances, not IP addresses. As per my comments on [amazon web services - How can I set ordinal based DNS names for ASG instances - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64394258/how-can-i-set-ordinal-based-dns-names-for-asg-instances), have a think about whether incremental numbers are truly required. Using InstanceId as a unique identifier should meet most of the requirements. There is the additional problem with spot and auto-scaling often adding/removing instances, which can ruin any incremental numbering scheme.